# date problem in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

if i have this in a string : `10/13/2010 8:38:40 AM`

how to make it to this: `13/10/2010 08:38:40`

thank's in advance

Comment: `myString = source == "10/13/2010 8:38:40 AM" ? "13/10/2010 08:38:40" : String.Empty`

Comment: I know too well that there are cultural, political, and other considerations and you don't always have a choice, but using anything other than the 'descending order by magnitude' format (i.e., yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss, or 2010/10/13 etc) is asking for trouble sooner or later. As you discovered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("10/13/2010 8:38:40 AM","MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

edited to make sure 24 hour clock is used in output

Answer (score 6):

Use `DateTime.Parse()` to convert to a true DateTime object and then use the `DateTime.ToString()` method to output to the format you desire (code example coming):

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("10/13/2010 8:38:40 AM");
var formattedString = dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss);
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
DateTime.Parse("10/13/2010 8:38:40 AM", new CultureInfo("en-US")).ToString(new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Since I know that those formats are for those cultures. However, you can read more about datetime formatting at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Standard formatting:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Custom formatting:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Or for a more general solution, just pass a format string to DateTime.ToString('*formatString*').  For example, what you want is DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").  This allows you to make any format you want.

Example:

```
DateTime exDT = DateTime.Now;  
string exOut = exDT.toString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Here's a cheat sheet! You can use ":" where you want it

```
d    Short Date
D    Long Date
t    Short Time
T    Long Time
f    Full date and time
F    Full date and time (long)
g    Default date and time
G    Default date and time (long)
M    Day / Month
r    RFC1123 date
s    Sortable date/time
u    Universal time, local timezone
Y    Month / Year
dd   Day
ddd  Short Day Name
dddd Full Day Name
hh   2 digit hour
HH   2 digit hour (24 hour)
mm   2 digit minute
MM   Month
MMM  Short Month name
MMMM Month name
ss   seconds
tt   AM/PM
yy   2 digit year
yyyy 4 digit year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var strfrom = "10/13/2010 8:38:40 AM";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strfrom, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-GB")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var curDate = DateTime.Now.ToString() ;
string customDateFormat = Convert.ToDateTime(curDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

another variant, one one line:

```
            DateTime.Parse("10/13/2010 8:38:40 AM", new CultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```