# how to deal with Unexpected date & time format's?

Tags: c#, winforms

i get date & time from Text file - to my string var in my C# program.

i need to convert this string var to datetime var.

how to do it, if i get unexpected type of date & time ?

and if i dont know the type of region on the host computer (when i Spread my program) ?

thank's in advance

Comment: Please formulate a precise scenario.

Comment: If you can't predict what format the strings are in it is almost impossible to correctly convert to datetime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933548/ and may others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TryParse which will return a boolean saying if the date is valid or not.

```
    string dateString = "03/01/2009 10:00 AM";
    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
    DateTimeStyles styles DateTimeStyles.None;
    DateTime dateResult;

    if(DateTime.TryParse(dateString, culture, styles, out dateResult))
    {
        do something with dateResult
    }
```

[TryParse docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, 2/3/2010 is ambiguous it could be mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy. If you use skyfoot's example you may get a valid date but not the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

**[TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wteydsd6.aspx)** is what you want.

```
DateTime result;

if(!DateTime.TryParse(unpredictableDate, out result))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Argument '" + unpredictableDate + "' was not a recognizable date format.");
}
```

Comment: Rejecting it with an exception is good.  But how do you figure that "bad format" is *more* informative then the exception you'd get when you just use DateTime.Parse?

Comment: @Hans, because the OP can copy/paste my code and instead of just running it, incorporate it into a larger framework where he customizes the error message to his liking. I modified the error message to be a little more helpful. If you are bulk processing, I would recommend inserting the errant record into a table for manual processing later, then continuing your batch.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Parse()` uses the culture settings from the PC where the app is running. That means the user can input the date formats of his culture.

If you do not want it this way specify the **Invariant Culture** when parsing then always english culture settings are assumed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are enforcing a specific date/time format, try using `DateTime.ParseExact`.